Need Assistance with Reducing PBF File Size in Tippecanoe
I am using the following command to generate MVT vector tiles using tippecanoe, but the output PBF files are too large (4+ MB each). My goal is to display all the geo data starting from the minimum zoom level. Below are the command details:
tippecanoe --force  --no-feature-limit --no-tile-size-limit --force-feature-limit --no-clipping --drop-rate=1 --minimum-zoom=5 --maximum-zoom=16 --layer=households --output-to-directory "output_dir" json_path

Requirement:

The PBF file sizes need to be reduced while still displaying the geo data starting from the minimum zoom level.

Attempts:

I've used settings like --no-feature-limit, --no-tile-size-limit, --force-feature-limit, and --no-clipping to ensure all data is retained.
Despite this, the file sizes are too large (4+ MB per tile).

Questions:

What configuration can I adjust to reduce the size of the PBF files without losing the visibility of data at the minimum zoom level?
Are there other optimizations I can apply to balance size and performance at lower zoom levels?

